# Data from controller does not get passed to the view in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-controller

I am trying to provide some hardcoded data (for the testing purposes only) from my controller like this

```
return redirect()->route('admin.my-view.edit', $prop)->withToastSuccess('Success')->with(['data' => ['test1', 'test2']]);
```

And in my edit page I am trying to dump data like this

```
@dump($data ?? '')
```

The issue is that I initially get `''` as well as after the redirect.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Could you please mark it as resolved, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You are using `with()` function which is a [flashed session](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) function and you have to get the the data value like that:

```php
@if (session('data'))
    // ...
@endif

// OR
session('data', '') // default value when no data session is passed
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [Redirecting With Flashed Session Data](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) by:

```
$test = ['test1', 'test2'];
return redirect()->route('admin.my-view.edit', $prop)->withToastSuccess('Success')->with(['data' => $test]);
```

then on blade:

```
{{ session('data') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
->with(['data' => ['test1', 'test2']])
```

in your blade view, you should do:

```
@dump(session('data') ?? '')
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this issue using cache. I make cache which gets removed after 10 seconds (just in case reload takes more time) and that is it.